# USE DB that may not exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a script that has a `USE DATABASE` statement.
The script runs perfectly fine if the database exists. If it doesn't exist, it fails with the message "the database doesn't exist", which makes perfect sense.

Now, I don't it to fail so I added a check to select if the DB exists on sys.databases (which I will represent here with a `IF 1=2` check for the sake of simplicity), so, if the DB exists (1=1), then run the "use" statement.

To my surprise, the script kept failing. So I tried to add a TRY CATCH block. Same result. 
It seems that the use statement is evaluated prior to anything else, which id quite annoying because now my script may break.

So my question is: how can I have an `use` statement on a script to a database that may not exist?

```
BEGIN TRY
   IF (1=1) BEGIN --if DB exists
    USE DB_THAT_MAY_NOT_EXIST
   END 
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
END CATCH
```

Comment: How big is this script @Diego? It might be easier to just fully qualify your table names, and wrap the whole script in an `if exists...` but that depends entirely on what you want to do if the database _doesn't_ exist.

Comment: Also, perhaps [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1037174/1220971) is a potential duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this? May be you could check in this way.

```
if db_id('dbname') is not null
 -- do stuff
```

or try this:

```
if not exists(select * from sys.databases where name = 'dbname')
    -- do stuff
```

So for table:

```
if object_id('objectname', 'somename') is not null
```

or

```
sp_msforeachdb ‘select * from ?.sys.tables’
```

[Reference](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/26/sql-server-list-all-the-tables-for-all-databases-using-system-tables/)

Comment: I ended up using your idea IF (db_id('$(dbname)') IS NOT NULL) BEGIN (its a vsql script). Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I don't believe you can do what you want to do.  The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188366%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) specifies that `use` is executed at *both* compile time and execution time.

As such, `use` on a database that does not exist is going to create a compile time error.  I am not aware of a way to bypass compile time errors.

As another answer suggests, use the database qualifier in all your names.

You can also check if a database exists, without switching to it.  Here is one way:

```
begin try
    exec('use dum');
    print 'database exists'
end try
begin catch
    print 'database does not exist'
end catch
```

Comment: that's actually a good idea, but the problem is that regardless of the database existing or not, I still need to "USE" it so the script will still fail

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head, you could fully qualify all your references to avoid the `USE` statement.
I hope someone comes up with a solution that requires less PT.

After doing your check to see if the DB exists, instead of

```
SELECT Moo FROM MyTable
```

use

```
SELECT Moo FROM MyDB.MySchema.MyTable
```

Comment: Lots of statements don't accept 3 part names. Such as create procedure