# Prevent selection of column if it does not exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have 2 tables of the same format in 2 separate databases.

**Database1**

```
_________  _____________________   _______________
Code(int)   Description(varchar)    Class(varchar)
_________  _____________________   ________________
```

**Database2**

```
_________  _____________________   ___________
Code(int)   Description(varchar)    Type(int)
_________  _____________________   ___________
```

I wish to write a generic query for my C# application which retrieves the values from both databases. I wrote the following query

```
DECLARE @DB = 'Database1'

IF(@DB = 'Database1')
BEGIN

SELECT 
    ID,[Description],Class
FROM MyTable

END

ELSE
BEGIN

SELECT 
    ID,[Description],Type
FROM MyTable

END
```

However the above query throws an error either for columns `Class` or `Type` when run for `Database2` or `Database1` respectively.

PS: I am making the connections with the DB correctly and also setting the parameter `@DB` accordingly. The logic is to run this query twice, once for `Database1` and fetch the respective `MyTable` with `Class` column and second time for `Database2` and fetch the respective `MyTable` with `Type` column.

I wish to know is it in any way possible to achieve what I am trying to do.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Use ordinal: Select 1,2,3 FROM MyTable.  Also, see this article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037174/sql-use-statement-with-variable.  Consider readability with this type of solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work, since:

> The entire request (batch) is parsed and compiled. If an error occurs
>   at this stage, the requests terminates with a compilation error

[source](http://rusanu.com/2013/08/01/understanding-how-sql-server-executes-a-query/)

You can try dynamic sql:

```
IF @DB = 'Database1'
BEGIN
    execute sp_sqlexec 
    'SELECT ID,[Description],[Class]
    FROM MyTable;';
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    execute sp_sqlexec 
    'SELECT ID,[Description],[Type]
    FROM MyTable;';
END
```

Answer (score 0):

use case statement

```
SELECT 
        ID,[Description],CASE WHEN @DB = 'Database1' THEN Class ELSE Type END
    FROM table
```

Comment: convert( varchar,CASE WHEN @DB = 'Database1' THEN Class ELSE Type END )