# Use local variable along with "use" statement in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, local-variables

I want to use a local variable with a `use` statement in SQL Server. I searched but could not find a proper solution.

```
   declare @var varchar(100)
   set @var = 'DB1'
   use @var
```

Comment: `use` takes a database name, not a string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sql use statement with variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037174/sql-use-statement-with-variable)

Comment: You can use `Dynamic SQL` or  Hard coded `IF` statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this,

```
DECLARE @var VARCHAR(100)
    ,@SQL NVARCHAR(max) = ''

SET @var = 'DBRND'
SET @sql = 'select name From ' + @var + '.sys.procedures'

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL
```

Comment: It is worth to mention that `DB1` is accessible only inside session of Dynamic query

Comment: This is working. But It does not solved my problem.
I am writing a procedure which will take database name as parameter and it will print all the list procedures of that database.
I am getting required information from sys.procedures table. 
But I am stuck at how to use database name which I will pass as parameter to SP inside "use" statement.